# Finding prime numbers using C does not work

Tags: c

I am currently learning C and trying to solve a problem. I need to find all the prime numbers from 2 to 100, using arrays and loops.

I already know of a solution to this problem however I am having trouble finding the error in my code. This is my first time using StackOverflow so hopefully I commented everything properly :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

  int prime_numbers[50] = {2,3};                //initializes the array which will be printed at the end
  int counter = 1;                              //initializes the index of the last prime element in array
  int checker = 0;                              //initializes a checker used to determine if the number is prime

  for(int i = 5; i <= 100; i++) {               //goes through numbers 5 to 100 as the first two primes are hard coded
    for(int j = 0; j <= counter; j++){          //goes through array untill it reaches last prime using the before initialized counter
        if(i % prime_numbers[j] != 0) {         //check to see if a number that is being checked is not divisible by j'th element in array
            checker++;                          //if so, checker is incremented
        }
        if(checker == counter + 1) {            //check to see if number was not divisible by any prime in our array
            checker = 0;                        //if so checker is reset to 0 for the next iteration
            ++counter;                          //counter is incremented as there is one more prime in our array
            prime_numbers[counter] = i;         //add inside array the found prime number
            break;                              //break should not be necessary, however for some reason, it yields a different result when I don't put it in
        }                                       //most likely the error in the code. Need to find out why loop does not stop after second if is done
    }
  }

  for(int g = 0; g <= 50; g++) {                //prints out all the prime numbers in array
    if(prime_numbers[g] != 0) {
        printf("%d ", prime_numbers[g]);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I expect the program to print all the prime numbers from 0 to 100 with spaces in between.

Comment: By "does not work" you mean it also finds numbers that are not prime? Note: the reporting loop breaks the array bounds, `g <= 50` should be `g < 50`.

Comment: at the end you need to flush the print writting the character \n, so `putchar('\n'); return 0;` at the end of _main_

Comment: Your programs do not compute prime number, lot of numbers are not prime, and on the reverse it misses 1

Comment: The logic is a rather strange inversion. The candidate needs to be divisible by only one prime in the list, to be a non-prime.

Comment: @bruno 1 is not a [prime number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number).

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes it finds numbers that are not prime as well.

Comment: @bruno :) 1 is not a prime number

Comment: @WeatherVane Yea, I know of other solutions too. I tried checking if a number is divisible by any prime already in the set. I am trying to understand why this does not work.

Comment: The checker variable needs to be reset back to 0 before the start of the inner loop.

Comment: Because it is a cack-handed way of going about it. I advise to stick with the way you know that works.

Comment: oh I always think 1 is primer, because can only be divided by 1 and of course itself :) thank you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program also finds numbers that are not prime. Its logic is a rather strange inversion. The candidate needs to be divisible by only one prime in the array. The reporting also breaks the array bounds.

The corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {                            // correct function signature

    int prime_numbers[50] = {2,3};
    int counter = 1;
    int checker;                            // initialise within each loop

    for(int i = 5; i <= 100; i++){
        checker = 0;                        // inintialise here
        for(int j = 0; j <= counter; j++) {
            if(i % prime_numbers[j] == 0) { // opposite test to yours
                checker++;                  // flag a non-prime
                break;
            }
        }

        if(checker == 0) {                  // moved outside the loop
            ++counter;
            prime_numbers[counter] = i;
        }
    }

    for(int g = 0; g < 50; g++) {           // corrected the bounds error
        if(prime_numbers[g] != 0){
            printf("%d ", prime_numbers[g]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");                           // flush the output buffer
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97
```

The reporting loop relies on the array being initialised to `0`s and a better way would be

```
for(int j = 0; j <= counter; j++) {
    printf("%d ", prime_numbers[j]);
}
printf("\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works well.

```
int main()
{
    int k=1,temp,j;
    const int N_prime = 10000;       // number of primes to be generated
    int primes[N_prime];             // array to save primes
    primes[0] = 2;
    primes[1] = 3;
    temp = 5;
    while (k!=N_prime-1){     // generating only N_prime prime numbers
        for (j = 0; j <= k && primes[j] * primes[j] <= temp; j++){
            if (temp%primes[j] == 0){    // if temp%primes[j] == 0 then temp is divisible by
                temp += 2;               // a prime and is not a prime itself, therefore 
                break;                   // immediately break
            }
            else if (primes[j+1] * primes[j+1]>temp){             // if no such primes found, temp is prime,
                primes[k + 1] = temp;                             // save it and increase the value for
                k++;                                              // next check
                temp += 2;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int ind = 0; ind < N_prime; ind++) printf("%d\n",primes[ind]);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

with the output:

```
2
3
5
7
11
13
17
19
23
29
31
37
41
43
47
53
59
61
67
71
73
79
83
89
97
101
103
107
109
113
127
131
137
139
149
151
157
163
167
173
179
181
191
193
197
199
211
223
227
229
233
239
241
251
257
263
269
271
277
281
283
293
307
311
313
317
331
337
347
349
353
359
367
373
379
383
389
397
401
409
419
421
431
433
439
443
449
457
461
463
467
479
487
491
499
503
509
521
523
541
```

As I noticed, your code generates all the odd numbers up to 100.